# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/webapp/php/signup.php

Tags: javascript, php

```html
<br /> <b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected ')' in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/webapp/php/signup.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
```

Deseo que aparezca un texto de error cuando trate de enviar un formulario vacío, pero en vez de eso solo es visible un problema en mi .js, he tratado de revisar pero hasta ahora no encuentro nada. Por favor si alguien puede indicarme dónde está el inconveniente y cómo podría solucionarlo le agradecería mucho :) Soy nueva en Js y este proyecto es una práctica.

```js
const form = document.querySelector(".signup form"),
continueBtn = form.querySelector(".button input"),
errorText = form.querySelector(".error-txt");
form.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}
continueBtn.onclick = ()=> {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "php/signup.php", true);
    xhr.onload = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                let data = xhr.response;
                if (data == "Perfecto") {
                } else {
                    errorText.textContent = data;
                    errorText.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        }
    };
    let formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

[image: Imagen del problema]

Comment: Hola Isabella ese error no es de javascript, es de php, si fuese de javascript lo verías en la consola, no en la propia página. Pon aquí el archivo signup.php y veremos donde tienes el fallo. Un saludo!

Answer (score -1):

revisa tu archivo signup.php, porque el servidor de XAMPP te esta marcando un error en la linea 9, y te dice que de esperaba un " ) ", posiblemente tengas algún paréntesis sin cerrar en alguna condición o función.

De todas maneras como te ha dicho el compañero DigiSoul, si dejas por aquí el código php lo veremos mejor.
Saludos.

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges) podrás dejar comentarios. Esto es una _no-respuesta_. Lee [answer].